# If true false parameter from variable grep

Tags: bash

the code:

```
 for i in {1..5}
 do
    PING=`ping -nq -w5 -c1 8.8.8.8`
    C=`echo $PING | grep "100% packet loss"`

    if $C; then
            echo "ok"
    else
            echo "not connected"
    fi
 done
```

If i use 8.8.8.8 it works but when i change it for ip which is not responding like 29.0.0.0 the error occurs : "There is no PING command". What is wrong ?

Comment: PING: no such command - it seems that it tries to run the content of $C variable

Answer (score 4):

```
if $C; then
```

Here the command `$C` and will be executed and it's return code decides which branch to take.

But what you really have is the output of a command and you want to check if it's empty or not.

Change it to:

```
if [[ -z $C ]]; then
```

`-z` checks if string is empty. If it's empty then no match for "100% packet loss" (ping passed).

*From manual:*

```
-z string
          True if the length of string is zero.
```

Comment: You don't need the double square brackets if you enclose `$C` in double quotes, this will make the code much more portable to other shells.

Comment: Question is tagged `bash`. bash built-in `[[ ]]` is preferred in bash than test (`[`). If I were to write, I'd prefer Cato's. Although grep's `-q` is not as portable.

Comment: If you're using double brackets in Bash, you can also just do `[[ $C ]]` to test for a zero string variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ -z "$C" ]; then
```

`-z` is zero length check, and `$C` is your variable. it's put in `[]` because that's an alias to the `test` command which returns true if the input is correct, or false otherwise.

You could also do

```
if [ "$C" = "" ]; then
```

Which would do a more traditional check for an empty string.

If you're really sure of what you want you could also go as far as:

```
if grep -q "100% packet loss" <<<"$PING"; then
        echo "not connected"
else
        echo "ok"
fi
```

Which uses grep's -q flag to do the check for results for us.

Answer (score 2):

The code following `if` is expected to be a list of commands, not a string. You need to explicitly test if the string has zero length or not; one way is to use

```
if [[ -z $C ]]; then
    # No output, so at least one packet got through
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not connected"
```

However, a better solution is to not check the output, but rather check the exit status of `grep`.

```
if ping -nq -w5 -c1 8.8.8.8 | grep -q "100% packet loss"; then
    # All packets lost, no connection
    echo "not connected"
else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Here, the `-q` option suppresses all output. You don't actually care about the line containing "100% packet loss"; you simply care if `grep` finds it or not.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    PING=`ping -nq -w5 -c1 8.8.8.8`

    if echo $PING | grep -q "100% packet loss"; then
            echo "ok"
    else
            echo "not connected"
    fi
done
```

The `if` command runs another command and it treats a zero result code as true, and any other result code as false.  This is why `if` is commonly used with the `test` command or the open bracket command, which is just another way to run `test`.

This also explains your original error.  It was trying to run the output of `ping` as a command.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to check if there's 0% packet loss. Sometimes you get a reply even if it's not exactly from 8.8.8.8:

```
for I in {1..5}; do
    if ping -nq -w5 -c1 8.8.8.8 | fgrep -q ' 0% packet loss'; then
        echo ok
    else
        echo 'not connected'
    fi
done
```